# Прокрутка изображения при прокрутке страницы с трансформацией

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, прокрутка, transform

Суть следующая, есть устройство, смотрящее на посетителя под углом. Хочу вставить в него изображение и имитировать прокрутку страницы. Выглядит это вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [картинка страницы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOIAD.jpg) для теста.

То есть, когда пользователь будет прокручивать страницу, внутри устройства будет прокручиваться "другая" страница с меньшей скоростью. Саму прокрутку не очень сложно прикрутить через JS, а вот как её точно и с адаптивностью вставить в экран, пока не придумал. Только если "на глаз", используя translate3d и transform, но, вариант не очень гибкий.

GIF-ку слепил для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: про вставить - https://codepen.io/GeorgePark/pen/QQZXNy?editors=1100

Comment: @Elena очень неплохо, спасибо. Правда адаптивности и в этом случае нет. Разве что весь контейнер уменьшать через `scale`.